# How to add fading effect to border like the image attached

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to achieve a div like this. I have the blue background and the foreground color. But I am not sure how to get fading border.

background color:- #93cde9

foreground color:- #c4e4f3

Can somebody help me out here??

[image: Required effect]

Comment: use shadows.. but it won't work in IE 8 or lesser :)

Answer (score 2):

```
div {
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #ffffff; 
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #ffffff; 
   -ms-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #ffffff;
   -o-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #ffffff; 
}
```

look: http://jsfiddle.net/waS6F/2/ :)

solution for IE:
[Box shadow in IE7 and IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8181699/box-shadow-in-ie7-and-ie8), [CSS3 Box Shadow Effect for IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899745/css3-box-shadow-effect-for-ie8)

hopely useful !

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with a `box-shadow?`

Here is a simple fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/GLmQd/1/

And here are some links for further reading

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-shadow

Answer (score 0):

For example you can use that.

```
<div id="img"><img ... /></div>

<style type="text/css">

#img{
border-style:1px solid green;
opacity: 0.3;
-webkit-transition: opacity .1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opactiy .1s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: opacity .1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: opacity .1s ease-in-out;
transition: opacity .1s ease-in-out;
}

#img:hover{
opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opactiy .1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity .1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity .1s ease-in-out;
}
</stlye>
```

Comment: Yeah and you can add shadow instead of border. 
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px #00FF00;

Answer (score 0):

This is how I achieved it:-

html:-

```
<div class="shadow-efect>
<div>
```

sass:-

```
.shadow-effect
  background-color: #b9daeb
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px #b9daeb
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px #b9daeb
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px #b9daeb
```